# Python List to Dictionary conversion via Comprehension

Tags: python, list, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

Say I have some function which returns a dictionary and I iterate over that function. This will produce a list of dictionaries. I wish to convert this into a dictionary. I am calling my function like this:

```
x = [_myfunction(element) for element in list_of_elements]
```

Resulting in say x:

```
x = [{'one': {'two':'2'}, 'three' : '3'}, {'four':'five', 'six':{'seven':7}}]
```

and I wish to convert into y:

```
y = {'one': {'two':'2'}, 'three' : '3', 'four':'five', 'six':{'seven':7}}
```

Is there a way of calling _myfunction() over the list_of_elements, such that it directly results in y? Maybe with a dictionary comprehension instead of the above list comprehension? Or what the most concise code to turn x into y. (Hopefully without being boring and using a for loop! :-) )

Thanks, labjunky

Comment: `y` is a *tuple* of dictionaries, hardly an improvement. Did you want to have *one dictionary* with keys `'one'`, `'three'`, `'four'` and `'six'` instead?

Comment: The `y` you want, is not a dictionary, it's a tuple of 2 elements (2 dictionaries).

Comment: If you truly want a single dictionary, you'll have to tell us what you want to do when one key appears in two (or more) dictionaries.

Comment: opps yes you are right. I have corrected it. In the case of identical keys, its ok to overwrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge dicts using the [dict.update](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) method:

```
y = {}
for element in list_of_elements:
  y.update(_myfunction(element))
```

You can also use a (double-loop) dict-comprehension:

```
y = {
    k:v
    for element in list_of_elements
    for k,v in _myfunction(element).items()
}
```

Finally, if you take any of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38987/2096752), for merging two dicts (and name it `merge_dicts`), you can use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) to merge more than two:

```
dicts = [_myfunction(element) for element in list_of_elements]
y = reduce(merge_dicts, dicts, {})
```

Either way, in case of repeated dict keys, *later keys overwrite earlier ones*.